# Showing that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{p(j)}\cdot b_j$ will converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $p$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and degree at least 1. Let $b_1\geq b_2 \geq \dots \geq 0$ and assume that $b_j\rightarrow0$. Prove that if $(-1)^{p(j)}$ is not always positive and not always negative then in fact it will alternate in sign so that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{p(j)}\cdot b_j$ will converge.

I am very lost on this problem. I notice that if the polynomial is $2j$ it will always return an even number and thus the series with be $b_j$ and if the polynomial is $2j+1$ the integer will be odd. But I don't know how to tackle the third case the problem is asking about. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is $pj$ supposed to be $p(j)$?

Comment: yes thanks I will fix that.

Comment: Just show that the polynomial alternates even and odd values. Note that the condition that $p(j)$ is not always even or always odd is equivalent to $p(j)$ having an odd number of non-constant coefficients that are odd.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $p(j)$ is a polynomial such that there exists $j$ such that 
\begin{align}
p(j) = a_0+ a_1 j+ \ldots + a_n j^n\equiv 1 \mod 2.
\end{align}
Consider the following case: if $j=2k$, then we see that
\begin{align}
a_0 \equiv 1 \mod 2.
\end{align}

Subcase 1: If $a_0 + a_1 +\ldots +a_n \equiv 1 \mod 2$ then it follows immediately that we have an alternating sum.

Subcase 2: If $a_0 + a_1 + \ldots +a_n \equiv 0 \mod 2$ then it follows for all $j$ odd $p(j) \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and for all $j$ even $p(j) \equiv a_0 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ which again leads to an alternating sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What can you say about the constant term of the polynomial, and about the sum of the coefficients of the non-constant terms, mod $2?$ What can you then say about the parity of $p(j)$ for $j$ even, and for $j$ odd?